# How to calculate the standard error of both kendall tau and pearson r correlation coefficients?

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to calculate the standard error of both kendall tau and pearson r correlation coefficients but I couldn't find any command for that in python.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr

x1 = [10, 18, 23, 24]
x2 = [2, 45, 7, 10, 0]
tau, p_value = stats.kendalltau(x1, x2)
r, p = pearsonr(x1, x2)
```